# Why does the compiler not completely optimize away the exception?

Tags: c++, exception, optimization

This program should always return 0 (unless I'm missing something):

```
int main()
{
    try {
        throw;
    } catch (...) { 
        return 0; 
    }
}
```

So why doesn't the entire exception get optimized away?

Gotbolt assembly with gcc 13.2 -std=c++23 -O3

```
main:
        push    rcx
        call    __cxa_rethrow
        mov     rdi, rax
        call    __cxa_begin_catch
        call    __cxa_end_catch
        xor     eax, eax
        pop     rdx
        ret
```

Comment: You know that your `throw;` is trying to _rethrow_ an exception that doesn't exist, right? _"This form is only allowed when an exception is presently being handled (it calls `std::terminate` if used otherwise)"_ -  Not that it matters if you actually `throw 0;` - the compiler still leaves code in there.

Comment: Probably because nobody has bothered optimising for such a non-sensical case. Every optimisation makes the compiler more complex, probably slower, is a source of potential bugs and takes developer time to implement so compiler developers will choose to optimise common cases, obscure cases unlikely to occur in real code will probably not be implemented

Answer (score 1):

> This program should always return 0 (unless I'm missing something):

No, `throw;` does not throw a new exception. `throw` without an operand *rethrows* a currently handled exception. If no such exception exists, it will cause a call to `std::terminate` to terminate the program.

So your program should terminate with a call to `std::terminate` instead of normally exiting with exit code `0`.

---

Assume for a moment that this wasn't the `main` function, but `notmain` instead.

Then it is possible that somewhere you do this:

```
try { throw 0; }
catch(...) { notmain(); }
```

This needs to be a noop, continuing execution after the statement.

It is also possible that you call `notmain()` somewhere, not enclosed by a `catch` handler. In that case you are trying to rethrow while no exception is active and therefore `std::terminate` needs to be called.

So the compiler has to have some logic in `notmain` that will check whether an exception is being handled and act accordingly, which is what is implemented behind these function calls you see in the assembly.

Now if the function is `::main` you can't possibly be handling any exception, so the program must always terminate with a call to `std::terminate` and the compiler could optimize for that, but that's a very specific and useless situation that is unlikely to be relevant enough to implement optimization for.